# Wireframe view makes everything invisible when in Object mode

Tags: transparency, wireframe, object-mode

A couple weeks ago, seemingly out of nowhere, the wireframe viewport mode suddenly stopped displaying a wireframe when in object mode, and just made all the objects invisible apart from their outlines. In edit mode the wireframe of the object being edited is shown but all the other objects remain invisible. Is anyone able to help me work out what weird setting I changed? I've even tried reinstalling blender as this issue has made working on this design much harder. (See pictures for further clarification)

[image: Objects displayed as solid]

[image: All objects become invisible and wireframe is gone when in wireframe mode]

Comment: Did this change in viewport behavior happen to coincide with an update to your graphics drivers? I'm guessing you have an AMD card? Latest Adrenalin drivers are the cause. Use an older driver version if you can.

Comment: It may have done yes, I do indeed have an AMD RX 580. I shall try to install an older driver version, thanks for the tip

Comment: Did installing old driver solved the problem? I do have the same issue also my graphic card is RX 580 too.